# how to use mistral client API against private mistral?

Tags: mistral-7b

I'm using mistralai.client to talk to the model instance in the Mistral cloud.
I've deployed my own instance on a cloud GPU and would like to use the same API against my private instance. Is this possible? I would like to specifically avoid switching to plain HTTP requests, if possible.